# Break span into few lines

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my `li` of *Brands*:

```
<li>
  <a href="#">
    <span style="">{{ brand.brand_name }}</span>
    <span class="pull-right product-amount">{{ brand.amount_of_products }}</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

[image]

**Case 2:** When width of `brand_name` span is almost equal the length of the whole `<li>`  the `product-amount` span is breaked to new line, but at the end (`6`) and the next `<li>` is shown incorrectly - its `product-amount` span is shown in wrong place.
**Case 1:** If the span is too long to fit the whole `<ol>` with length `200px` - everything works correctly.
**Is there a way to break a long span into few lines of defined length authomatically?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the layout with `position: relative` and `postion: absolute`.

Try adding the CSS rules like below.

```
<li>
  <a href="#">
    <span class="brand-name">{{ brand.brand_name }}</span>
    <span class="pull-right product-amount">{{ brand.amount_of_products }</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

```css
li {
  padding-right: 60px;
  position: relative;
}

.product-amount {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks very much like tabular data, and therefore I would recommend that you use a table to display it. That would solve the crux of your problem "automatically" as well as displaying the data in the most efficient and suitable manner.